# How to use PHP framework in old core PHP project

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have an old core PHP existing project and I would like to keep the old code as it is but for any new files or updated use Laravel framework.

I can install and run Laravel framework but how do I manage my `.htaccess` file so that routing is done properly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Rather than alter your htaccess configurations, to keep them entirley separate, I think I would dump your whole Legacy project into a new Services folder within your Laravel App.  Then create a new Controller that points to it.  It'd give you the opportunity to peal off sections of the Legacy project later, to refactor it into the new framework properly.  And it'd give any new features for it access to Laravel's library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard PHP project where you go straight to the `.php` file. Just throw them in your `public` folder.

Which would look something like this on your local testing machine

```
localhost:8000/public/about.php
```

But once you launch the site, then it will be normal:

```
www.yoursite.com/about.php
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this. I would suggest migrating the project fully to the Laravel framework.

You could run into some issues with URL names, be very careful as your going to be possibly dealing with a lot of `500 errors`.

Comment: I do not have direct  `.php` files. We have `rewrite_delegator.php` which changes the url to slugs.